# Why doesn't Android Studio let me select a device and run an app?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

With the [firebase-android-client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/firebase-android-client) demo app, the device selector in Android Studio says "Not applicable for firebase-android-project configuration".

However, if I create a new project from the "Basic" project wizard, I can successfully launch the app.

I installed several (virtual) devices, including one for Android 6.0.

My app does not run with this disabled device, nor do I have the choice to select another device.

Below are screenshots of the project where it works and the one where it doesn't.

What needs to be fixed? How do I launch this simple demo project?

- Problematic:
  [image: "Not applicable" message]
- Working:

[image: Working]

- Run/Debug Configuration for App
  [image: Run/Debug Configuration for App]
- If I just push the green Run button, the Gradle console gives me `Executing task... Task execution finished.` but nothing else happens.

Comment: Can you attach Run/Debug Configuration screenshot?

Comment: I see now. The problem was that a Gradle configuration was selected, not the app configuration.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. If you could write this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to tackle the situation you need to check the **Run/Debug Configuration** and apply appropriate configurations there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you have selected a Graddle configuration to run (`firebase-android-client`), not an app one.

If you select the `app` in the `Select Run/Debug Configuration` dropdown it will work fine.

[image]